# Linq - How can i use "this" inside of a "select new" statement

Tags: linq

**Edited:**

I'm querying some XML into objects recursively. Each object has a list of sub objects, and should refer to it's parent if it has one.

Example XML:

```
<object attribute1="text" attribute2="text"/>    
<object attribute1="text" attribute2="text">
    <object attribute1="text" attribute2="text">    
    <object attribute1="text" attribute2="text">    
</object>
```

Example Linq:

```
    private static List<MyObject> ParseMyObjects(XElement node, MyObject p)
    {
        List<MyObject> myobjs = (from x in node.Elements("object")
                                select new MyObject {
                                    attribute1 = x.Attribute("attribute1 ").Value,
                                    attribute2 = x.Attribute("attribute2 ").Value,                                     
                                    subObjects = ParseMyObjects(x, this), // the "this" key word can't refer to the MyObject being created in the query, but is there some other way of doing this?
                                    parent= p
                                }).ToList();
        return myobjs;
    }
```

To accomplish this currently, I am recursively traversing the MyObjects list AFTER it has been queried and setting each parent (the "parent" line above is excluded).

I would simply prefer a more elegant solution of using the newly instantiated object within the Linq query if possible. Any ideas?

**Edit:**
To clarify (as BrokenGlass did in a comment), the *this* that the code comment is referring to is the instance of MyObject that is being created within the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to harness the set of the subObjects property on MyObject.

```
class MyObject {
....

private List<MyObject> _subObjects = new List<MyObject>();
public List<MyObject> subObjects 
{
    get { return _subObjects ; }
    set 
    { 
        _subObjects  = value;
        if(_subObjects != null)
        {
            foreach(MyObject o in _subObjects )
            {
                o.parent = this;
            }
        }
    }
}

....
}
```

If anyone does know of a way to reference the newly created/selected object within the Linq syntax, I will mark your answer as the corrrect one.

Answer (score 2):

`this` can't work in a method marked `static` ever. There is no instance because the method is static.

> I would simply prefer a more elegant solution of using the newly instantiated object within the Linq query if possible. Any ideas?

Just use [`XObject.Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.parent.aspx) as in

```
parent = x.Parent
```

Comment: I think the the `this` OP refers to is the instance of `MyObject` that is being created, which has nothing to do with whether the method containing the Linq query is static or not - neither has `XObject.Parent` because its not a `MyObject`

Comment: @BrokenGlass: The OP chose unfortunate terminology then, especially since he said "the "this" key word does not work here." The `this` keyword explicitly and only (except in defining extension methods) ever refers to the current instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, i posted the question wrong :/ The conversation here actually still applies to getting the current instance from the created object within the Linq query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `Parent` member of the created `MyObject` instance to point to the instance itself, there are two ways to achieve this without adding code that iterates over the list after the Linq query:

1) Add a constructor that sets it up for you, e.g. the default constructor

```
public MyObject() {
    this.Parent = this;
}
```

2) Add a fluent-interface style method for setting the parent, and invoke it in the query:

```
/* in class MyObject */
public MyObject WithSelfAsParent() {
    this.Parent = this;
    return this;
}

/* updated linq query */
List<MyObject> myobjs = (from x in node.Elements("object")
                                select new MyObject {
                                    attribute1 = x.Attribute("attribute1 ").Value,
                                    attribute2 = x.Attribute("attribute2 ").Value,                                     
                                    subObjects = ParseMyObjects(x),                                  

                                }.WithSelfAsParent()).ToList();
```

Whether these are better than explicitly looping over the list is of course a matter of taste. I would probably just keep it simple and choose the loop, unless the assumption that the parent pointer is equal to this by default is obvious in the context of your `MyObject` class, which makes setting it in the default constructor the natural choice.

Comment: Unfortunately, i posted the question wrong :/ I have since edited it. As for my original posting, this would have been the answer. Sorry about that. I up voted you if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote - I think the cure is worse than the disease here, it is not immediately possible but could be done using some variant of my "fluent-interface" suggestion where you pass the function to set the children as a callback parameter. But I think your solution for setting the parent is better.

Comment: Ya, the setter solution is better than the extra loop in a calling method. Thanks for your help, and thanks for being nice even though i screwed up :)